# transliteration in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

Do we have a good transliteration options..? As I have come to know that Google and Microsoft Transliteration services are Paid. I want to build a website where have to provide devnagari typing. But, not able to find correct approach and reference to start off. My techniology is in ASP.net and sql server DB